# Первый элемент массива пустой, во втором первый элемент и так дальше, как поправить?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
//Есть компонент родитель Content
function Content() {
let [cart, setCart] = useState([])
function addCart() {
    arrCart.push(cart)
    // console.log(typeof arrCart, arrCart)
  }
return (
    <ContentContext.Provider value={{cart, setCart, addCart}}>
    <div className={styles.content}>
        <Goods />
        <Cart />
    </div>
    </ContentContext.Provider>
  );
}
//Компонент Goods он выводит товары которые можно добавить в корзину
function Goods() {
const {setCart} = React.useContext(ContentContext)
return (
// Код который выводит товары на страницу
//Кнопка которая должна добавлять в корзину()
<button onClick={()=> { addCart() return setCart(roll)}} className={styles.btn__add} type='button'>Add</button>
//Компонент Cart сюда я должен получать массив
import { arrCart } from '../Content';
function Cart() {
console.log(arrCart)
return ()
}
```

Ошибся исправил, теперь выводит мне массив добавляет, но первый элемент он добавляет пустой со второго добавляет первый и так дальше.